# SOAP exercises. Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing

Tags: php, soap

I'm doing some SOAP exercises based on this example: **http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2009/03/simple-php-soap-example/**

But, I cannot get that to work on WAMP.

Error which I'm getting is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL:
Couldn't load from 'http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso?WSDL' :
failed to load external entity "http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso?WSDL" 
in C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Desktop\Dropbox\wamp\soap\index.php:5 Stack trace:
#0 C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Desktop\Dropbox\wamp\soap\index.php(5): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://football...') 
#1 {main} thrown in C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Desktop\Dropbox\wamp\soap\index.php on line 5
```

Line 5 is: `$client = new SoapClient("http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso?WSDL");`

Uncle Google does not know the answer. Any suggestion much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port 8080 on that host seems to be closed, that will be the problem. Contact them.

Actually,  try using a proxy server like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient(“http://someaddress?WSDL”, array(‘proxy_host’ => “example.proxy.com”,’proxy_port’ => portnumber));
```

Comment: what do I write in "example.proxy.com"?